# How to use insertAfter() when given a specific node in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

```
// insert a new data after the given one
public void insertAfter(int givenData, int newData){
   // Your code here
   Node previous = new Node(givenData);
    if (previous == null) {
        //System.out.println("The given previous node cannot be null.");
        return;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node(newData);
    newNode.next = previous.next;
    previous.next = newNode;
}

// Removes the Node with the given data
public void remove(int current) {
  // Your code here
  Node previous = new Node(current);
    int count = 1;
    int position = 0;
    while (count < position -1) {
        previous = previous.next;
        count++;
    }
    Node curNode = previous.next;
    previous.next = curNode.next;
    curNode.next = null;
}
```

This code is not giving any error messages, but the nodes will not be added or removed. I believe my confusion lies with *int givenData* and how to access that if its not a node. First post here, hopefully I gave enough information :)

```
public class LinkedListTemplate {
Node head;


// inserts data to the end of the list only using the head pointer
public void append(int data){
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if(head == null){           
        head = newNode;

    } else {            
        Node currentNode = head;
        while(currentNode.next != null){
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        currentNode.next = newNode;             
    }
}

// inserts data to the beginning of the list
public void prepend(int data){
    if(head == null){
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

// print the linked list elements
public void print() {
    Node currentNode = head;
    System.out.printf("[");
    while (currentNode.next != null) {
        System.out.printf("%d, ", currentNode.data);
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    System.out.printf("%d]%n", currentNode.data);
}

// counts the length of the list
public int length(){
   int length = 0;
   Node currentNode = head;
    while(currentNode != null){
        length++;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }   
    return length;
}

// get an item from the list specified by the index
public int get(int index){
   int len = length();
   if(index > len){
      return -1;
   }

 Node currentNode = head;
 int currentIndex = 0;
 while(currentNode != null){
    if(index == currentIndex){
       return currentNode.data;
    }
    else{
       currentNode = currentNode.next;
       currentIndex++;
     }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

I included the rest of the linked list code, there is also another class that tests the list and allows it to run.

Comment: I probably should have included this:

Sample Input/Output 

11 23 31 -1 37 41 should output the following:

The list contains: [11, 23, 31] 
The length of the list is 3.

Inserting a new node after the first node. 
Now the list contains:[11, 37, 23, 31].
Inserting new data after the third node. 
Now the list contains:[11, 37, 23, 41, 31].
The length of the list is 5. 

Removing the second element: 
Now the list contains:[11, 23, 41, 31] 
Removing the head 
Now the list contains:[23, 41, 31]

list is created I just need to figure out how to insert the nodes and remove them.

Comment: all good! I just don't see how to give a reasonable/usefull answer without that ;) please edit your quetion(easier to reed!) and I ment the actual list in your code: there should be some root or anchor element at least ;)

Comment: @kai I added more info (:

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you probably need to enhance your code a bit. First, you need a list. So let's start with that.

```
public class MyLinkedList {
    public Node *head = NULL;
}
```

head points to the front of your list.

Now, the basic algorithm for insertAfter is simple:

1. Find the node that contains the "where to insert after" value
2. Create a new node and insert it after.

Cute, huh?

```
void insertAfter(int beforeData, int valueToInsert) {
    Node *ptr = head;
    Node *lastPtr = NULL;
    while (ptr != NULL && ptr->value != beforeData) {
        lastPtr = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    // At this point, ptr COULD be null, if the data is never found.
    // Insertion is at the end, and lastPtr helps with that.
    Node * newNode = new Node(valueToInsert);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        # At the end of the list.
        if (lastPtr != NULL) {
            lastPtr->next = newNode;
            newNode->previous = lastPtr;
        }
        else {
            // The entire list is null
            head = newNode;
        }
    }
    else {
        // ptr points to the data we were searching for, so insert after.
        newNode->next = ptr->next;
        newNode->previous = ptr;
        ptr->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
MyLinkedList list;
list.insertAfter(0, 1);
list.insertAfter(1, 17);
list.insertAfter(1, 10);
```

If you then dump the contents of the list (you'll need to iterate from head through the next pointers), you'll see the list contains in order 1, 10, 17.

Comment: Can you look at my edited post? I added the list I have created

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try.

Please note that I actually didn't know what the remove realy is supposed to do.

Your code was looking for a node with a given index so I stuck to that(1rst remove version).

But the comment suggested, that you need to remove the node with a given data. So I added a second version, that does that(2nd remove version).

```
    public void insertAfter(int givenData, int newData) {
        // Your code here
        Node previous = head;
        while (null != previous && previous.data != givenData) {
            previous = previous.next;
        }
        // this prevents insertion if given Data was not found 
        if (previous == null) {
            System.out.println("the given data doesn't exist");
            return;
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(newData);
        newNode.next = previous.next;
        previous.next = newNode;
    }
```

Version that removes the node with a given index:

```
    // Removes the Node with the given index
    public void remove(int current) {

        Node previous = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < current - 1; i++) {
            if (null == previous) {
                System.out.println("the given position doesn't exist");
                return;
            }
            previous = previous.next;
        }
        if (current == 0) {
            head = head.next;
        } else if (previous.next == null) {
            System.out.println("the given position is after the end - nothing to do!");
        } else {
            previous.next = previous.next.next;
        }
    }
```

Version that removes the element with given data

```
   // Removes the Node with the given data
    public void remove(int data) {
        Node previous = head;
        if(head == null){
            System.out.println("Empty list - nothing to remove!");
            return;
        } if (head.data == data){
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }

        while(previous.next != null && previous.next.data != data){
            previous = previous.next;
        }
        if (previous.next == null) {
            System.out.println("the given element was not found - nothing to do!");
        } else {
            previous.next = previous.next.next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Got it :) Thank you so much!! Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

change insertion method to this:

```
public void insertAfter(int givenData, int newData) {
    Node n = head;
    while (n != null && n.data != givenData) {
        n = n.next;
    }
    if (n != null) return;
    Node newNode = new Node(newData);
    newNode.next = n.next;
    n.next = newNode;
}
```

and Remove method with this:

```
public void remove(int current) {

    Node prev = head;
    if(head == null) return;
    if(head.data == current){head = null; return;}
    Node n = prev.next;
    while( n != null && n.data != current){
      prev = n;
      n = n.next;   
    }
    if (n == null) return;
    prev.next = n.next;

}
```